# Remove some <br /> tags from XML weather feed

Tags: html, xslt, rss, tags

I'm trying to format a weather feed on my site via an RSS XML, which is easily acheived. The trouble is that it renders cascading down the page, and I want to have it running across the page.

From what I can gather, it looks as though I need to get rid of the `<br /><br />` tags so they will align next to each other.

The XML source looks like this:

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[ <b>Wednesday</b>
    <br />
    <img src="/images/icons/fcast_30/mostly_cloudy.gif">
    <br /> Mostly cloudy<br /> -1&#176;C - 14&#176;C
    <br /><br />
    <b>Thursday</b>
    <br />
    <img src="/icons/fcast_30/frost_then_sunny.gif">
    <br /> Frost then sunny<br /> 1&#176;C - 13&#176;C
    <br /><br />
    <b>Friday</b>
    <br />
    <img src="/images/icons/fcast_30/rain.gif">
    <br /> Rain<br /> 2&#176;C - 11&#176;C
    <br /><br />
    <b>Saturday</b>
    <br />
    <img src="/images/icons/fcast_30/clearing_shower.gif">
    <br /> Clearing shower<br /> 0&#176;C - 12&#176;C
    <br /><br /> ]]>
</description>
```

My output XSL code look a little like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="rss/channel">
    <xsl:value-of select="(item/title)[2]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring((item/description)[1],30,15)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="(item/description)[2]" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And the output renders to look like this:

**Wednesday**
IMG.gif
Mostly cloudy
-1°C - 14°C
**Thursday**
IMG.gif
Frost then sunny
1°C - 13°C
**Friday**
IMG.gif
Rain
2°C - 11°C
**Saturday**
IMG.gif
Clearing shower
0°C - 12°C

How would I go about removing the `<br /><br />` tags after each day so they align next to each other, but leaving the other singular `<br>` tags?

Comment: The "source XML' as provided, doesn't have any of the element names (`rss`, `channel`, `item`, `title`, `description` ). Please, edit the question and provide the *real* source XML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As already noted by others, the wanted transformation is impossible, unless the CDATA section (that makes the markup just regular, plain, one-dimensional text) is removed**.

---

**This complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "br[preceding-sibling::node()
       [self::* or self::text()[normalize-space()]
        ][1]
        [self::br]
    or
     following-sibling::node()
       [self::* or self::text()[normalize-space()]
        ][1]
        [self::br]
    ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the XML document obtained after removing the CDATA section and correcting numerous malformedness errors**:

```
<description>
        <b>Wednesday</b>
        <br />
        <img src="/images/icons/fcast_30/mostly_cloudy.gif"/>
        <br /> Mostly cloudy<br /> -1&#176;C - 14&#176;C
        <br /><br />
        <b>Thursday</b>
        <br />
        <img src="/icons/fcast_30/frost_then_sunny.gif"/>
        <br /> Frost then sunny<br /> 1&#176;C - 13&#176;C
        <br /><br />
        <b>Friday</b>
        <br />
        <img src="/images/icons/fcast_30/rain.gif"/>
        <br /> Rain<br /> 2&#176;C - 11&#176;C
        <br /><br />
        <b>Saturday</b>
        <br />
        <img src="/images/icons/fcast_30/clearing_shower.gif"/>
        <br /> Clearing shower<br /> 0&#176;C - 12&#176;C
        <br /><br />
</description>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<description>
   <b>Wednesday</b>
   <br/>
   <img src="/images/icons/fcast_30/mostly_cloudy.gif"/>
   <br/> Mostly cloudy<br/> -1°C - 14°C
            <b>Thursday</b>
   <br/>
   <img src="/icons/fcast_30/frost_then_sunny.gif"/>
   <br/> Frost then sunny<br/> 1°C - 13°C
            <b>Friday</b>
   <br/>
   <img src="/images/icons/fcast_30/rain.gif"/>
   <br/> Rain<br/> 2°C - 11°C
            <b>Saturday</b>
   <br/>
   <img src="/images/icons/fcast_30/clearing_shower.gif"/>
   <br/> Clearing shower<br/> 0°C - 12°C
            </description>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies "as-is" every matched node, for which it is selected for execution.
2. There is a single template overriding the identity template. It matches any `br` whose *first* sibling (either preceding-sibling or following-sibling) that isn't a whitespace-only text node, is also a `br`.
3. This overriding template has empty body, which effectively "deletes" any matched `br` element from the output.

Comment: I think you've succumb to the copy-and-paste beast, because the output XML seems to be the same as the input XML...

Comment: @TimC, Thanks for noticing this -- fixed now. Sometimes my keyboard doesn't react to Ctrl+C and then paste uses the previously copied text, not the one I think should be pasted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **DON'T** put XML inside a CDATA section unless you are forced to do so by other parties.

Assuming that you have moved the XML content to outside of a CDATA section, apply an XSLT style-sheet with the identity transform and this template ....

```
<xsl:template match="br[
  preceding-sibling::node()[self::br] |
  following-sibling::node()[self::br] ]" />
```

This template will remove adjacent <br> elements. If there is any text between the two <br>s, even just white space, the <br>s will not get removed.

---

#### Note

This solution is wrong. See Dimitre's answer.

Comment: Sean, unfortunately the proposed solution doesn't produce the wanted result.