# Remove <BR>html tags in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need to remove the `<BR>` tags using xslt template. The problem is that the data is neither xhtml complainant or Html, but certainly considered legal by HTML.

I have provided the sample data below. We are using strip tag template to remove the html tags in the date but, we still have `<BR>` tags that needs to be removed and rendered correctly.

Sample data:

```
"<BR>Line1 Is here<BR><BR>Line2 Is another<BR><BR>Line3 Is some more"
```

Some case there can be multiple `<BR>` tags so I need to render the data recursively.

PS: The product supports only Version 1 of xslt.

Comment: Which XSLT version and which XSLT processor do you use or can you use? Is that sample the complete input? The usual input to XSLT needs to be well-formed XML, if you want to parse HTML instead then you need to check whether your XSLT processor allows plugging in an HTML parser or has some extension to parse HTML, as for instance http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse-html.

Comment: We are using version 1. I am not entirely sure of what processor being used as its a product, I have only provided sample data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove some <br /> tags from XML weather feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962748/remove-some-br-tags-from-xml-weather-feed)